# Printing array of object in .blade template

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm making an `HTTP Request` using `Guzzle` to an external API an getting some data as a response like this:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$res = $client->get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
return view('home')->with('result', $res->getBody());
```

But I don't know how to print it in a `<li>` in my `.blade` template. What's the workaround?

Comment: can you please print it using print_r() and update the array

Comment: did you try and loop like `foreach` ?

Comment: who voted down and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getContents()` method to get response data and decode the json response using `json_decode`, Like this:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
$posts = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
return view('home', compact('posts));
```

In your `blade` file you can render them as list items like so:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <li> {{ $post->title }} </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```